# Определение типов в динамически типизированных языках

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, perl, common-lisp

Пишу на динамических языках как Python, Common Lisp и тд. И вот, бывает просматриваю исходный код библиотек, если у них не хватает документации, и бывает проблема определить какого типа входные данные ожидает функция, конструктор и тд. В статическом языке я бы это увидел по описанию типа, а тут приходится гадать. Может есть какой-то способ узнавать какой тип ожидается, о котором я не знаю?
Например, функция ждет параметр с именем  id. В условном с++ я бы увидел string id, и понял бы.

Comment: Ну если библиотека настолько плоха, что у неё нет документации и из исходников непонятно что передавать, то может лучше не использовать её?

Comment: Дык а как понять их исходников что передавать, если там допустим имя bot, а в библиотеке три класса ***_bot и структура bot допустим

Comment: Ну надо смотреть что там с этим bot потом происходит. В общем, формальный ответ: из сигнатуры функции никак. В этом и сила (и слабость) динамической типизации.

Comment: Подойдёт любой объект, у которого есть нужный набор свойств и методов. А какой набор нужен, это уж должно быть написано в документации...

Comment: В случае с js можно перейти на тайпскрипт, под который адаптированы почти все либы (нужно только доустановить типы) и спокойно смотришь эти моменты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чаще всего, используемая библиотека все-таки содержит документацию. Плюс сейчас еще модно использовать опциональную стат.типизацию в Python и Ruby, как раз для этих целей.
Самый простой способ - посмотреть исходники. Если не помогает - запустить REPL (командой python для Python, irb для Ruby) и передать все мыслимые типы, которые, как вы подозреваете, могут подойти.
Оптимистичный способ - инструменты вывода типа. Обычно такие встроены в IDE и могут дать подсказку. Есть более продвинутые инструменты командной строки (typeprof в Ruby с недавних пор поставляется сразу), которые помогут вывести тип почти из любого кода.